# Are Samhitas apauresheya?

Tags: shiva, samhita

About the Samhitas books. I wish to know who composed these books, what are these books related to (itihasa, smritris, srutris or others) in the canon of Sanataan Dharma. I mean: which integrant part do these books constitutes? Are from Agamas or Vedas? Are they related with Shiva and or are His words?

Editing:

Only referring to Samhitas and in particular to Shiva Samhita and Yoga Shiva Samhita.

Not mentioning all the corpus of the Vedas per se.

Asking how to collocate them.

Archit already answered well.

The suggested other answer fulfills other requirements more generic about the entire corpus of the Dharma literature.

Both answers are very well done but my question required a more synthetic and short answer which deal with a particular part of the corpus.

Thanks to both the members anyway :)

Comment: Samhitas are the main mantra part of the Vedas. They are supposed to be apauresheya (non man made) but at the same time realised by Rishis in their meditative state or so.

Comment: Thank you so much. I am happy to read Shiva Samhita then! But my edition is sanskrit without romanized characters and a translation in english that I do not know if is authentic but I hope so. Please suggest me a version with romanized sanskrit and whose translation in english you know is correct. Bahut Danyavaad.

Comment: Partially.The answer of @Archit is exactly what I was looking for. Yet your answer gives a more generic and exhaustive compendium description about the Canon of the Dharma, its vast literature. Hence very good ;)

Comment: see pages 1-19 here - https://archive.org/details/IndianPhilosophyACriticalSurvey/mode/2up

Comment: The Shiva Samhita you're talking about is not a Vedic Samhita. It is a Yogic scripture. @hindustudent

Comment: Well thank you. Any pdf of original Samhitas of Shiva and (if exists) of other Gods? @Swami Vishwananda

Comment: Yes @Rickross I understand that and I feel that the answer of Archit satisfied me. I had the feeling that this was Yogic into Vedas, yet I am reading everything. If someone can provide me all the Puranas and all the Agamas I will read these too. Around Vedas there are the contributions of other texts. Thanks to those most ancient texts, Vedas do exist.